# AngularJS Controller not accepting passe din value on click

Tags: angularjs

When the end user clicks on a pencil icon it will load up a model to edit a location:

**HTML:**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#locationModal" ng-show="true" ng-click="editLocation(ACQ1121)"><i data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="far fa-pencil" data-original-title="Edit"></i></a>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.editLocation = function(locationId) {
   $scope.model.location = {};
   $timeout(function() {
       vm.getLocation(locationId);
       $scope.model.action = "Edit Location";
   });
};

this.getLocation = function(locationId) {
   angular.copy($scope.model.locations.filter(function (x) { return x.id === locationId; })[0], $scope.model.location);
};
```

`$scope.model.locations`
`[...
  ...
  {RowId: 3, id: "ACQ1121", name: "Meldrum", Submitted: null, SubmittedBy: null, …}
 ...]`

However when im debugging `$scope.editLocation = function(locationId){}` i keep getting `locationId = undefined`, i cant seem to see whats going wrong here? Not sure why `locationId` is undefined when we get to `$scope.editLocation`

Comment: `editLocation('ACQ1121')` is the correct version. You were trying to give the variable $scope.ACQ1121 to editLocation ...

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanks!

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant put that as the answer so i can give it to ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`editLocation('ACQ1121')` is the correct version.

You were trying to give the variable $scope.ACQ1121 to editLocation, not the string `'ACQ1121'`.